# mechanize: specified module could not be found (unf_ext.so)

Tags: ruby, automation, mechanize

I'm trying to do something with Mechanize and I'm not getting past the most basic example:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'mechanize'

agent = Mechanize.new
```

Seems simple enough, but all I get is this error:

`:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in 'require': 126: 
The specified module could not be found.

- D:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/unf_ext-0.0.3/lib/unf_ext.so (LoadError)`

Things I've tried:

- installing gem unf_ext directly (works, same error result though)
- bundle install
- bundle update

There is a Mechanize mailing list but it seems to have very low activity. I think I might actually get my question answered here on SO.

My environment is Windows 7 with RubyMine.

Update: this is a bug in Devise that the team is currently (2011-12-07) working on.